# Method for finding best result from (almost) random data

Tags: python, algorithm, heuristics

So I'm working on some calculator for a game I play - for fun, which takes various abilities with different cooldowns, usage times, a percentage in which they may be used at etc ...

So far I am doing this by analyzing numbers in base however many abilities I have, so for example assuming i have 5 abilities used over 4 seconds:

0000: 60 damage (using ability 0, trying to use it again but failing - so returns ability damage of 0)

0001: 60 damage

Skip a few ...

0101: 200 damage

and again ...

4444: 70 damage.

Process terminates. - Hope that made sense.

Problem is, doing this in brute force works well with small times (like above) and number or abilities, however at much higher times and number of abilities it runs analyzing trillions of simulations which means brute force no longer becomes an option.

Question is, considering the data is mostly random, are there any heuristic algorithm's that (all thought may not return the optimal) will return a relatively good result.

Thanks for any responses :)

Comment: What have you tried thus far? We're here to help when you're stuck with a specific programming problem, not so much creating entire solutions :) (Pro tip: search for "bitwise operations")

Comment: I have made the actual program itself trying brute force and trying random paths - that's about it. Was going to ask if there were any more convenient solutions for this type of problem?

Comment: it is still too vague and unclear ... may be a small sample set of your data-base would be a good idea to share + 2 examples of actual  state with description which is better and why... from that we (you included) can start to thinking about heuristics

Answer (score 0):

Let me rephrase to make sure I understand correctly: you want to find the best sequencing of skills, given their individual damage and cooldowns, such that only one skill is used at each time, and no skill is used more often than its cooldown allows. If so, it is a kind of a scheduling problem and one way to approach would be through [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming).

The rough idea is to introduce `n_skills * simulation_length` variables `x[skill][time]`, each constrained between 0 and 1, with the interpretation of "use skill `skill` at time `time` if `x[skill][time] == 1`, don't use if `== 0`". Now you optimize the sum of all variables weighted by the damage their skill does, `sum(x[skill][:] * damage[skill] for skill in skills)`, under additional linear constraints (explained through `numpy`-like pseudocode):

1. for each time `t`, `sum(x[:][t]) <= 1` (at each time you can use at most one ability)
2. for each ability `a` and time `t0` `sum(x[a][t0-cooldown(a):t0+cooldown(a)] <= 1` (within the period of its cooldown, you can only use your ability at most once)

Now the tricky part is that while this will give you a solution that is optimal in some sense, it will most likely not be *physical*, that is you'll get fractional `x`s. This is where the heuristic part kicks in, you have to find some way to "round" the solution to integers, losing objective value in the process, to make it physically (game-ally) meaningful. One way is to only keep `x[a][t] == 1`, and round all other numbers down to zero. It will give a meaningful solution, but it may not be very satisfying (ie. your character will do almost nothing). Given that my model for the problem is quite simple, I would expect there are some theoretical results on how to give a good rounding.

While I can suggest the [scipy package](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html) for solving the linear program once it's formulated, the whole problem of building the constraint matrix and rounding the results (even trivially) is not a beginner-level programming task.